# Init.d script gets return code 1 when calling itself, how can I get output?

Tags: scripts, services, init.d, debug

My question is, how can I modify the script so that it will tell me what goes wrong?

The scenario is this:
I'm trying to get Sonatype Nexus to start as a service in Ubuntu 10.04, and it just will not work.

(I'm not looking for help on how to run Nexus, but on how to get some useful output from a script)

It works when invoking it with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nexus start
```

but fails when using

```
sudo service nexus start
```

I have run the update-rc.d command on it, and done everything according to instructions.

The nexus init.d-script has a point where it calls itself when it detects that it should run as another user ('nexus'):

```
su -m $RUN_AS_USER -c "\"$REALPATH\" $2"
```

which expands to

```
su -m nexus -c '"/opt/nexus-2.0.2/bin/jsw/linux-x86-64/nexus" start'
```

when adding the -x debug flag to the script. This command results in return code 1. It never executes - I've set -x debug flag on the script, placed echo commands with redirect to file at the start of script to trace, etc.

I cannot get any output telling me why the command will not execute. I've tried appending redirect to file after the above script line, inside the quotes, outside, any way I could imagine. All info I can get is by inserting a line

```
echo $?
```

after the su line, which outputs '1'.

Is there a way I can see what happens when the su command runs?

Comment: su - USER -c "commands" Why are you using -m?
su -m USER...

Comment: You say it never executes (when you use `set -x`), so it fails at an earlier stage? could you provide the xtrace output perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the user wasn't set up as system user correctly. (Don't use the adduser command for that.) Try to delete user nexus and re-add it.

```
sudo groupadd nexus
sudo useradd -r -g nexus nexus
```

Don't forget to chown the home of the nexus binaries and the sonatype-work directory and also the directory where the script puts the PID file to the new user.

Comment: Why not just add `nexus` to `nexus` with `sudo usermod -a -G nexus nexus`?

Comment: Better to use `adduser` than `useradd`. It has a `--system` option for creating system users.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I locked down the nexus user to use `/bin/false` as it's shell. Because this part of the script executes a shell command passed to `su` as an argument, this caused the script to just exit right there.